# Did Sri Ramanujacharya attain nirvikalpa Samadhi

Tags: vedas, advaita, atma, vishishtadvaita, samadhi

Did Sri Ramanujacharya ever  attain nirvikalpa samadhi or Dharmamegha samadhi and at last Maha Samadhi ?